# Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am running an ipython script on VS code. The file is a .py where I run the jupyter cells using the '# %%' line separator.

Random cells are giving me this

> Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session XXX

And the XXX changes every time. The problem is that the code gets frozen and does not finish nor provided the output of the cell.

All the solutions I have found in SO don't exactly relate or don't solve my problem so far.
[image]

Comment: Also experiencing this issue. Furthermore, the "Interrupt" is not working so the only way I have to stop execution would be to reset the entire kernel and re-run.